# print statement executes more times than expected

Tags: python-3.x

```
k = 0
while k < 8:
    if k % 2 == 0:
        print('in da loop')
    k = k + 1
```

OUTPUT:

```
in da loop
in da loop
in da loop
in da loop
```

This `in da loop` was output 4 times.
Because I am thinking `in da loop` should be only output once.
Subsequent output should be like:
`k = 0+1 = 1`
since `k=1 & greater than 0`
There should be no further output.

Comment: Please indent your code, so we can see what is inside which suite.

Comment: the result of k%2 is the remainder of the division by 2 and can be 0 (when k is an even number or 0) or 1 (when k is an odd number). You print when the remainder is 0, so you print everytimes k is an even number, which is k=0,k=2,k=4,k=6

Comment: Hey Jeryll, thanks mate. this make more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this python code (whitespace is important in Python!):

```
k = 0
while k < 8:
    if k % 2 == 0:
        print('in da loop')
    k = k + 1
```

There are eight iterations of the loop.
Only four of those numbers are even.
So the `print` happens four times.

For this code:

```
k = 0
while k < 8 and k % 2 == 0:
    print('in da loop')
    k = k + 1
```

The `print` will happen only once. If you expected your loop only to print once, you meant to also put the other check in the `while` loop.

Personally, if you expect to only have one print, I would shorten your code to this:

```
print('in da loop')
```

Comment: Ok, I got it now. As long as the remainder is 0. It prints. This makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Indented like this

```
k = 0
while k < 8:
    if k % 2 == 0:
        print('in da loop')
    k = k + 1
```

If will print "in da loop" four times, when k is 0, 2, 4 and 6.

Indented like this:

```
k = 0
while k < 8:
    if k % 2 == 0:
        print('in da loop')
        k = k + 1
```

It will print "in da loop" once and the loop never ends.

Comment: The loop will end, when the unexpected indentation of `k = k + 1` is encountered. If `k = k + 1` is indented the same as the preceding `print`, then the loop will run forever, with `k` stuck at 1.